# Set variables at and depending on compile-time

Tags: java, eclipse, compile-time-constant

Is there any way to set a constant to a value which depends on the time of compilation? I want my application to have a

```
public static final String RELEASE_DATE = "<???>";
```

similar to

```
#define RELEASE_DATE __DATE__
```

in C, which contains the date when the version was compiled. Of course I could change it manually everytime but there has to be a better way.
Do Java and/or Eclipse give any possibilities to achieve that although Java does not have a preprocessor?

Comment: Why do you want that to be hard-coded in the class file? Have you considered the manifest file or a properties file in META-INF?